# Unable to load module with inject-loader

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js

In my vue.js project I have the following file at `src/api/user.js`

```
import { HTTP } from '@/services/http'

export const user = {
  login (email, password) {
    return HTTP.post('v1/login', { email: email, password: password })
  }
}
```

I'm trying to load this file using inject-loader inside my specs:

```
const actionsInjector = require('inject-loader!../../../../src/api/user')
```

it returns me following error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../../src/api/user' in '/home/mateusz/projects/e_lessons_frontend/test/unit/specs/store/user'
```

How can I fix that?

UPDATE:

After adding one extra `../` I have new error:

```
  Error: Some of the injections you passed in are invalid.
  Valid injection targets for this module are:
  - @/services/http
  The following injections were passed in:
  - @/api/user
  The following injections are invalid:
  - @/api/user
```

This caused by this line of code in my tests:

```
// create the module with our mocks
const actions = actionsInjector({
  '@/api/user': {
    login (email, password) {
      return { token: 'dupa' }
    }
  }
})
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably need an extra `../`

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question because I have another problem. It would be great if You can take a look.

Comment: Not familiar with `inject-loader` but from the warning it seems like your module is expecting `'@/services/http'` and you are passing in `'@/api/user'`. Maybe one of those needs to change